# AngularJS doesn't update scope in ng-repeat properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-form

I've got multiple problems, please, see the demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0OWI81TxYBVHoaEVAXw5?p=preview).

Here you can see a simple `ng-repeat` loop. If you type in the last row you will get one more (no more than 5). `x` removes a line

The first problem: if you type smth and then delete a non-last line then the last line's inputs are marked dirty.
The second problem: if you click the "Cancel" button some fields are also marked as invalid.

`$scope.$apply` doesn't help. In `$timeout` as well.

Thank you for all the ideas and help in advance!

Comment: I noticed you define `ng-repeat` in `<form>` tag. So you create multiple forms. I made some changes [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/UmpARpjXTFfETcdY5MRF?p=preview). I don't know if this is close to your needs. You can take a look if you want.

Comment: This code is not updating `$scope.form` and checks this object in `remove` function also for validation so it messes up everything. I tried to fix it but it was a little tricky.

Comment: @lzagkaretos I wanted for the last line to be a new form, so that not to be invalid. that's it:)

Comment: @ata I have to use `.form`. otherwise I can't get a form in the controller

Comment: Remove `track by $index`. It will work better.

Comment: @georgeawg that works, cool, thank you very much, you literally saved me:) however, why are you considering my question as duplicate? actually it not that obvious (until you're working with AngularJS regularly) that validation problems were cause by `track by $index`. I would say the question might be useful in terms of seeing what problems you may face with when you're using the construction. anyway, thank you very much one more time!